# Excel Public Function Returns "VALUE#" for Certain Numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making a simple Excel sheet for me and my dad, brothers, etc to keep track of car maintenance.  I have some programming background but not enough to figure out this issue.  The issue is that when certain number strings are pulled in to the function and then put into the equation, it gives a #VALUE! error.  See below for and example:

Cell B9: Replace @ miles:185555

Cell D9: 41446

Cell E9: =IF($G$2-$D9>=getMiles(B9),"SERVICE!","OK")

Cell G2: 60000

If I enter 18555 in E9, I get "OK" instead of the error.

If I enter 40000, I get the error.

Also, this happens if I change the equation to nothing more than =getMiles(B9).  Same exact thing.  It's not the number of digits, obviously.  But, anything over a certain amount seems to trigger the error.  I don't know if it's a hex thing or bug, or my code.  Please help.  See below for the miles equation and feel free to download the excel sheet from my link.  Thanks in advance for your efforts.

```
Public Function getMiles(cellie As String) As Double

Dim pos As Integer
Dim milesStr As String
Dim milesTrimmedStr As String
Dim milesInt As Integer
Dim number As Integer

pos = InStr(cellie, "miles:")
number = pos + 6
milesStr = Mid(cellie, number, 7)
milesTrimStr = Trim(milesStr)
milesInt = CDbl(Val(milesTrimStr))

getMiles = milesInt


End Function
```

Link to my Excel file: https://filedropper.com/filemanager/public.php?service=files&t=1c6edf91310c639743bfcd09b0fbb80c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the variable `milesInt` from being type `Integer` to type `Double`. You are overflowing the integer variable.

In VBA, `Integer` variables are 16-bit, with values split between positive and negative, so the largest positive number which can stored is 2^15-1 = 32767. This is why your function couldn't handle 40,000. Since your function returns a double, it makes sense to declare that variable as `Double`. The other `Integer` variables can be declared to be `Long` (even if overflow isn't a danger). With modern machines there really isn't much point in using 16-bit integer variables in VBA.

Comment: Works perfect.  As you can see, I had some tiny thought in my head that it might need to be double, so I changed the return type, but forgot to change the internal variable.  Embarrassing and just pathetic thinking on my part.  Thanks so much for your succinct, accurate and prompt response!  May the programming gods have mercy on my soul....